# Mapping over arrays in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I'm mapping over each object inside the array of objects inside my state's item property. The issue is, I want to be able to attach a button to each returned item that only works with that item, and not the other items too. Here's what I have so far:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        item: [],
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            item: [
                {
                    name: 'jacob',
                    hair: 'brown',
                    sex: 'male',
                }, {
                    name: 'hannah',
                    hair: 'brown',
                    sex: 'female',
                }
            ]
        })
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        var x = Object.assign({}, this.state)
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                { this.state.item.length > 0 ? 
                    (
                        <div className="row mt-5">
                            <Item item={ this.state.item } handleChange={ this.handleChange } />
                        </div>
                    ) : null
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Item extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="col">
                { this.props.item.map(s => (
                    <div>
                        <div className="mt-5">{ s.name }</div>
                        <button onClick={ this.props.handleChange } value={ s.name }>Click</button>
                    </div>
                 ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So for instance, if the button's fx was to change the name property of the item it was rendered with, I want it to **only** change that item and no other items should be affected. Whenever I iterate through it attaches the button's fx to every item, so if I click it for one, I'm really clicking it for all of them, and that's exactly what I don't want.

For those curious, I'm setting the state in componentDidMount to simulate calling an API.

Also, the fx that's currently running in the handleChange is just some messing around I was doing trying to figure out values and a solution to manipulating a nested object inside an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this refactored code on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2o85yx0yrr),
You have to add keys when iterating Components in React, i've added it, also the **Item** Component could be **function Component** since it doesn't handle a state.

**Updated:**  below is the code in case it wouldn't be available on codesandbox.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      items: [
        {
          name: 'jacob',
          hair: 'brown',
          sex: 'male',
        }, {
          name: 'hannah',
          hair: 'brown',
          sex: 'female',
        }
      ]
    })
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {items.length && (
          items.map((item, index) => (
            <div className="row mt-5" key={index}>
              <Item item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
          ))
        )
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Item = ({ item, handleChange }) => (
  <div className="col">
    <div className="mt-5">{item.name}</div>
    <button onClick={handleChange} value={item.name}>Click</button>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I was thinking I'd probably have to use keys, but how would I go about actually accessing that key? For instance, how would I console.log the name value of the second element, or in other words console.log "hannah?"

Comment: @JacobLockett, you could see the console in codesandbox! just click on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to pass the individual element in to your `handleChange`:

```
  { this.props.item.map((s, i) => {
      <div>
        <div className="mt-5">{ s.name }</div>
        <button key={i} onClick={ (s) => this.props.handleChange(s) } value={ s.name }>Click</button>
      </div>
   })}
```

This way, you will have the individual `item` passed in as an argument, so when you are writing your `handleChange`, you can do whatever you want with just that item and not the whole array.